# jquery show/hide button and tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, tooltip

I am trying to make a show/hide button with jquery and I would also like the tooltip/title to change when the button is hovered over with the mouse but it isn't working at all.

my code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYA6q/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input id="button" type='button' value='Not Clicked' title = 'Not Clicked'>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Not Clicked")
    {
        $(this).val("Clicked");
        $(this).attr("title", "Clicked");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val("Not Clicked");
        $(this).attr("title", "Not Clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possible to change this.val to this.text? I tried and it says that there is an unexpected call to method or property access. and I tried another way in a different fiddle and it doesn't work at all http://jsfiddle.net/FBNMJ/

Comment: Why would you want to change val to text?  The documentation says text uses the val method.

Comment: Actually on the jQuery `.text()` documentation page it says exactly: `The .text() method cannot be used on input elements. For input field text, use the .val() method.`